# All possible middle elements, for largest odd length palindrome subsquence of a string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How to find all possible middle elements for the longest palindrome subsequence of a string  . 
Considering that the length of longest palindrome subsequence is odd .

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the logic for [Longest Palindromic Subsequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-12-longest-palindromic-subsequence/) and extend it for your case.

Let **DP(i,j,k)** denote the maximum answer with j as the middle element and current index is i and k. Now

```
if(i==j && j==k)
    return 1;
if(S[i] == S[j])
    DP(i,j,k) = 1 + DP(i+1, j, k-1)
DP(i,j,k) = max(DP(i,j,k), max(DP(i+1,j,k), DP(i,j,k-1)))
```

calculate it for all possible values of i,j,k , the maximum value would be your answer. Time Complexity **O(n^3)**